# How to enlarge divs on top of other content on mouseover to reduce need to scroll overflow content? Am using Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation

I have 9 divs that are boxes. Each box includes data (used Some Text repeated over and over again in my example) that does not fit within the box itself. When I mouseover on top of any box, I want that box to "enlarge and be able to overlap other boxes" so that I can see more information without having to scroll. Animation is a plus. What would be a good way to accomplish this? Is it a directive or something else? The following is my code in vanilla html/css.

Pictures of what I am looking at before:

[image]

Pictures of the result after mouseover to animate to. Note that what is not shown is the box is bigger (due to bigger dimensions) that it shows more text content that may help to eliminate scrolling:

[image]

```css
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
table {
  border:1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}
td {
  text-align:center;
  background:red;
  padding:  10px 0;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;  
  background:yellow;
}

.heading{
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
        <span class="heading">Box1</span>
        <div class="scroll">
        Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
     
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="heading">Box2</span>
      <div class="scroll">
        Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box2</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box4</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box5</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box6</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box7</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box8</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box9</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an extra wrapper between the cell and the header/box to make it work with CSS only (one can do it without, but it gets much more complicated how to deal with the scaling, transition etc.).

Since when zoomed in, it cover the cells closest to itself, I added a delay on the transition, so one have time to re-position the cursor over the box of choice. Another option would be to scale it a little less, but I tried that and it didn't look so good, so I went with the delay version.

Would this be something you could use?

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
* {
position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  border: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
tr {
  height: 33.333%
}
td {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 33.333%
}
td > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: yellow;
}
.heading {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) > div {
  transform-origin: left top;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) > div {
  transform-origin: center top;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) > div {
  transform-origin: right top;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) > div {
  transform-origin: left center;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) > div {
  transform-origin: center center;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) > div {
  transform-origin: right center;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) > div {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) > div {
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) > div {
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

td:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
td > div {
  transition: transform .5s;
}
td:hover > div {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: transform .5s .5s;
}
td:hover > div * {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  width: 200%;
}
td:hover > div span {
  height: 10px;
}
td:hover > div div {
  height: calc(200% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span class="heading">Box1</span>
        <div class="scroll">
          Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span class="heading">Box2</span>
        <div class="scroll">
          Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box3</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box4</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box5</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box6</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box7</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box8</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>

      </div>
    </td>
    <td>

      <div>
        <span class="heading">Box9</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Based on a comment, here is an attempt to make the text not shrink prior to the zoom in.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
* {
position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  border: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
tr {
  height: 33.333%
}
td {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 33.333%
}
td > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: yellow;
}
.heading {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) > div {
  transform-origin: left top;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) > div {
  transform-origin: center top;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) > div {
  transform-origin: right top;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) > div {
  transform-origin: left center;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) > div {
  transform-origin: center center;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) > div {
  transform-origin: right center;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) > div {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) > div {
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) > div {
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

td:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
td > div {
  transition: transform .5s;
}
td > div * {
  width: 100%;  
}
td:hover > div {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: transform .5s .5s;
}
td:hover > div * {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  width: 200%;
  transition: transform 0s .5s, width 0s .5s, height 0s .5s;
}
td:hover > div span {
  height: 10px;
  color: white;
}
td:hover > div div {
  height: calc(200% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span class="heading">Box1</span>
        <div class="scroll">
          Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span class="heading">Box2</span>
        <div class="scroll">
          Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box3</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box4</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box5</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box6</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box7</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div>

        <span class="heading">Box8</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>

      </div>
    </td>
    <td>

      <div>
        <span class="heading">Box9</span>
        <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Based on a second comment, one can also add a class-based CSS rule, and then by toggle that same class on a cell, manually trigger an animation.

Here is an update of the CSS rules to accomplish that

```
td.zoomin > div,
td:hover > div {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: transform .5s .5s;
}
td.zoomin > div *,
td:hover > div * {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  width: 200%;
  transition: transform 0s .5s, width 0s .5s, height 0s .5s;
}
td.zoomin > div span,
td:hover > div span {
  height: 10px;
  color: white;
}
td.zoomin > div div,
td:hover > div div {
  height: calc(200% - 10px);
}
```

And something like this for the script

```
var box = document.querySelector("td:nth-child(2)");
box.classList.add("zoomin");
```

Comment: This is very good. Is there a way to make it so the text doesn't shrink before it zooms out?

Comment: @Rolando Thanks...updated with a second sample. Made the header text white on hover, so one get some kind of indication something is going on.

Comment: This is perfect! Just curious, might there be some way to say, add an external button that manually triggers the animation for a specific box? (i.e. Box 2)

Comment: @Rolando Yes, but that is going to cost you an upvote ;) ... duplicate the 4 hover rules, `td:hover > div` etc., and then use a class instead, `td.zoom-me > div`, and then, by toggle a class on the box of your choice, i.e. Box 2 would be `td:nth-child(2)`, you can manually trigger the animation. Was I clear enough with this description?

Comment: @Rolando Already added a sample of the CSS to my answer, is it enough?